# Ruby on Rails: Processing a form that is not linked to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm having difficulties implementing this. Moreover, I come across the "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" error on the index page of my controller.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :potentialcandidates, :only => [:index, :send, :process]
get 'potentialcandidates/send' => 'potentialcandidates#send', :as => :send_potentialcandidate
post 'potentialcandidates/process' => 'potentialcandidates#process', :as => :process_potentialcandidate
```

**potentialcandidates_controller.rb**

```
  class PotentialcandidatesController < ApplicationController
   def index
    end

   def process
    @name = params[:name]
    @email = params[:email]
    # Add user to user model
    @user = User.create(email: @email, name: @name, status: "active")
   end
 end
```

**index.html.erb**

`<a href="<%= send_potentialcandidate_path %>">Add</a>`

**send.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_tag process_potentialcandidate_path do %>
      <%= text_field_tag "name" %>
      <%= text_field_tag "email" %>
      <%= submit_tag %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Whats the rest of the index page? Your error comes from sending a parameter to a method that doesn't take any.

Comment: That's all that is on my index page, a link to the form.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is coming from index then?

Comment: I am getting the error here: http://localhost:3000/potentialcandidates. Wouldn't that be the index page?

Comment: Also, why not use a `link_to` instead?

Comment: I know. I just meant to say that i'm getting error at /potentialcandidates. Also I just changed it to link_to i.e. <%= link_to "Add", send_potentialcandidate_path %> and it is still not working.

Comment: That error cannot be from your index page... you aren't passing a parameter to anything.

Comment: I noticed when I remove the process method from the controller, the page shows up. However, the form won't work.

Comment: The specific error I get is: app/controllers/potentialcandidates_controller.rb:5:in `process' ... I don't think I'm passing any arguments to process though.

Comment: So then the problem is in your process method. You should have mentioned that you were getting the problem when you were submitting the form. Please show the rest of the process method.

Comment: What I have above what I have in my process method (so far).

Comment: You only have the two assignments? That doesn't make sense. It is saying on line 5: `@name = params[:name]`, you are passing in a parameter to a method that doesn't take any.

Comment: I tried giving process parameters, but nothing changes.

Comment: That's... not the problem. I don't think that that is exactly what is currently in your controller. Line 5 up there is `@name = params[:name]`

Comment: Would @name = params[:name] be the correct way of retrieving the value of name in the form?

Comment: If you needed to use @name in the view, that's fine.

Comment: There should be a line between end and def process... Sorry. Line 5 is "def process"

Comment: Those kinds of things are important! :)

Comment: I know this is really bad advice, but have you tried turning your Rails server off and on again? I have seen situations where it helps...

Comment: Ah, I see now. You can't use `process` as a controller method. It is used in `ActionController::Base`.

Comment: Tried turning it on and off again, doesn't work lol. Should I rename it?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I like putting the logic you have in your controller into a form object.  Then you can stick to a simple controller with regular actions.  Check out #3 here: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process` is a method in `ActionController::Base` and you do not want to override it in your controller.

Change the name, update your routes and form, and restart the server; it should work just fine.

Comment: I added an empty send method to the controller and I come across the same error.

Comment: `send` is also a method in `ActionController::Base`

Comment: Remember that you will need to make the necessary changes to your routes and views as well.

Comment: Thanks it works! I have a second question... I'm trying to fetch information from one form and create a new record in a model called User. Do I have to do anything after I call User.create() ?

Comment: User.create will make an entry in your database. If you want to use that information later, you will have to use ActiveRecord to pull that entry back out.